# Display an image inline with imagepng()

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I've consulted the PHP manual to try and invert the colors of an image, but I can't get the image to display the way I need it to.

Essentially, within a WordPress loop, I need to take an image, invert it, and then set the background image of a div to that inverted image. Here's my code so far:

```
<?
if (have_rows("slideshow")):
    while (have_rows("slideshow")):
        the_row();
        $icon = get_sub_field("icon");
        $image = get_sub_field("image");
?>
<button data-slide="<? echo $image["url"] ?>">
    <div class="icon" style="background-image:url('<? echo $icon["url"] ?>');">
        <?
        function negate($im) {
            if (function_exists("imagefilter")) {
                return imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
            }
            for ($x = 0; $x < imagesx($im); ++$x) {
                for ($y = 0; $y < imagesy($im); ++$y) {
                    $index = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
                    $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($index);
                    $color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255 - $rgb["red"], 255 - $rgb["green"], 255 - $rgb["blue"]);
                    imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $color);
                }
            }
            return(true);
        }
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($icon["url"]);
        if ($im && negate($im)) {
            echo "Image successfully converted to negative colors.";
            imagepng($im);
            imagedestroy($im);
        }
        ?>
        <!--<span style="background-image:url('img/icon-circle-white.png');"></span>-->
    </div><!--/.icon-->
    <div class="caption">
        <h2><? the_sub_field("title"); ?></h2>
        <? the_sub_field("caption"); ?>
    </div><!--/.caption-->
</button>
<?
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

This works, but it spits out a bunch of weird characters instead of the image. It seems to me that the problem is `imagepng()` requires `header("Content-type: image/png");`, but I can't do that because this is within a WordPress loop, not a separate file.

My idea is to externalize the image inversion stuff, and run that separate PHP against every image that I specify in the loop (ex: `<img src="/invert.php?url=<? $icon['url'] ?>" />`. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can use buffering with `ob_get_contents` and embed an image base64 encoded contents with `data:image/png;base64,___`.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a shot. Can you point me to a tutorial? I'm not very good with PHP.

Comment: Are you uploading the images via the worldpress uploader or just pulling them form URL's or another directory on your server to embed them into your post? If you're not intelligently setting a background color (which you don't seem to be since you have circle-white.png) and the background why not us CSS3's invert(100%) filter since an inverted image is the same as a negative. Unless you need to have the images saved for something later.

Comment: I'm uploading to WordPress; the user will be able to change out the icons themselves. I would like to use CSS3's filters, but they're not pervasive enough to be viable at this point. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is to deploy the image-data inline like so:

```
    <?php
    //...
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($icon["url"]);
    if ($im && negate($im)) {
        echo "Image successfully converted to negative colors.";
        //read the imagedata into a variable
        ob_start();
        imagepng($im);
        $imgData=ob_get_clean();
        imagedestroy($im);
        //Echo the data inline in an img tag with the common src-attribute
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($imgData).'" />';

    }
    //...
    ?>
```

This does have some downsides:

- The entire computaion is done on every Page refresh
- Browsers do not cache the imagedata and will therefore always download the entire image

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this does help. It'd be best to have the images cache, but this looks like the path I'll have to go down.

Comment: Yes, I agree. If you want to display this image more then a few times, it might be better to save it to the disk and then delete it, if it is not needed anymore.